# Does WSO2 api manager support SCIM APIs?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, scim2

I found that WSO2 identity server has a set of SCIM APIs.

Would like to know if there are a same set of APIs for WSO2 api manager?

If yes, then how to enable it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 API Manager does not have the SCIM API support. You have to use Identity Server for this.